# What is the purpose/behavior of the syntax (<any> new Classname)

Tags: typescript

```
let instance = new ClickerApp((<any> new PlatformMock), (<any> new MenuMock));
```

is an example from: https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/blob/master/src/app/app.spec.ts

Is this a cast?  What's going on here?

Comment: This is a *kind of* a cast. In TS it's called type assertion (see more info [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html) + explanation for name). Since `PlatformMock` doesn't satisfy `Platform` type, it is casted to `any` to avoid type error. Type `any` basically fits for any (:D) other type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-assertion.html)

> The reason why it's not called "type casting" is that casting generally implies some sort of runtime support. However type assertions are purely a compile time construct and a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

In your case, you are passing mock objects instead of actual. 
`any` allows unsafe assertions since it is compatible with all types and therefore the compiler no longer complains about type. However, you would miss the compile time type checking. The better approach in this case would be to use [interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html) (which is structural sub typed aka duck typed) and DI.